# Nodejs/express - Router.use() requires middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn)); No app.use('/',routes);

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I recently ran into this error pretty much out of no where, I actually changed nothing on my system. I am however using a source code that was written between 3-5 years ago. I am very stumped because it doesn't actually reference a file where I use `app.use('/',routes);`. That is the only thing I could find on this site that was similar to my issue.

```
/root/bustabit-webserver/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:458
      throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
      ^

TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object
    at Function.use (/root/bustabit-webserver/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:458:13)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/root/bustabit-webserver/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:220:21)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function.use (/root/bustabit-webserver/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:217:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/bustabit-webserver/server/index.js:95:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:736:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:747:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:568:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:3)
```

**ROUTES.JS**

```
var admin = require('./admin');
var assert = require('better-assert');
var lib = require('./lib');
var database = require('./database');
var user = require('./user');
var games = require('./games');
var sendEmail = require('./sendEmail');
var stats = require('./stats');
var config = require('../config/config');
var recaptchaValidator = require('recaptcha-validator');


var production = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

function staticPageLogged(page, loggedGoTo) {

    return function(req, res) {
        var user = req.user;
        if (!user){
            return res.render(page);
        }
        if (loggedGoTo) return res.redirect(loggedGoTo);

        res.render(page, {
            user: user
        });
    }
}

function contact(origin) {
    assert(typeof origin == 'string');

    return function(req, res, next) {
        var user = req.user;
        var from = req.body.email;
        var message = req.body.message;

        if (!from ) return res.render(origin, { user: user, warning: 'email required' });

        if (!message) return res.render(origin, { user: user, warning: 'message required' });

        if (user) message = 'user_id: ' + req.user.id + '\n' + message;

        sendEmail.contact(from, message, null, function(err) {
            if (err)
                return next(new Error('Error sending email: \n' + err ));

            return res.render(origin, { user: user, success: 'Thank you for writing, one of my humans will write you back very soon :) ' });
        });
    }
}

function restrict(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.user) {
       res.status(401);
       if (req.header('Accept') === 'text/plain')
          res.send('Not authorized');
       else
          res.render('401');
       return;
    } else
        next();
}

function restrictRedirectToHome(req, res, next) {
    if(!req.user) {
        res.redirect('/');
        return;
    }
    next();
}

function adminRestrict(req, res, next) {

    if (!req.user || !req.user.admin) {
        res.status(401);
        if (req.header('Accept') === 'text/plain')
            res.send('Not authorized');
        else
            res.render('401'); //Not authorized page.
        return;
    }
    next();
}

function recaptchaRestrict(req, res, next) {
  var recaptcha = lib.removeNullsAndTrim(req.body['g-recaptcha-response']);
  if (!recaptcha) {
    return res.send('No recaptcha submitted, go back and try again');
  }

  recaptchaValidator.callback(config.RECAPTCHA_PRIV_KEY, recaptcha, req.ip, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      if (typeof err === 'string')
        res.send('Got recaptcha error: ' + err + ' please go back and try again');
      else {
        console.error('[INTERNAL_ERROR] Recaptcha failure: ', err);
        res.render('error');
      }
      return;
    }

    next();
  });
}


function table() {
    return function(req, res) {
        res.render('table_old', {
            user: req.user,
            table: true
        });
    }
}

function tableNew() {
    return function(req, res) {
        res.render('table_new', {
            user: req.user,
            buildConfig: config.BUILD,
            table: true
        });
    }
}

function tableDev() {
    return function(req, res) {
        if(config.PRODUCTION)
            return res.status(401);
        requestDevOtt(req.params.id, function(devOtt) {
            res.render('table_new', {
                user: req.user,
                devOtt: devOtt,
                table: true
            });
        });
    }
}
function requestDevOtt(id, callback) {
    var curl = require('curlrequest');
    var options = {
        url: 'https://www.bustabit.com/ott',
        include: true ,
        method: 'POST',
        'cookie': 'id='+id
    };

    var ott=null;
    curl.request(options, function (err, parts) {
        parts = parts.split('\r\n');
        var data = parts.pop()
            , head = parts.pop();
        ott = data.trim();
        console.log('DEV OTT: ', ott);
        callback(ott);
    });
}

module.exports = function(app) {

    app.get('/', tableNew()); // Changed the default index page to play page {staticPageLogged('index')}
    app.get('/register', staticPageLogged('register', '/play'));
    app.get('/login', staticPageLogged('login', '/play'));
    app.get('/reset/:recoverId', user.validateResetPassword);
    app.get('/faq', staticPageLogged('faq'));
    app.get('/contact', staticPageLogged('contact'));
    app.get('/request', restrict, user.request);
    app.get('/deposit', restrict, user.deposit);
    app.get('/withdraw', restrict, user.withdraw);
    app.get('/withdraw/request', restrict, user.withdrawRequest);
    app.get('/support', restrict, user.contact);
    app.get('/account', restrict, user.account);
    app.get('/security', restrict, user.security);
    app.get('/forgot-password', staticPageLogged('forgot-password'));
    app.get('/calculator', staticPageLogged('calculator'));
    app.get('/guide', staticPageLogged('guide'));


    app.get('/play-old', table());
    app.get('/play', tableNew());
    app.get('/play-id/:id', tableDev());

    app.get('/leaderboard', games.getLeaderBoard);
    app.get('/game/:id', games.show);
    app.get('/user/:name', user.profile);

    app.get('/error', function(req, res, next) { // Sometimes we redirect people to /error
      return res.render('error');
    });

    app.post('/request', restrict, recaptchaRestrict, user.giveawayRequest);
    app.post('/sent-reset', user.resetPasswordRecovery);
    app.post('/sent-recover', recaptchaRestrict, user.sendPasswordRecover);
    app.post('/reset-password', restrict, user.resetPassword);
    app.post('/edit-email', restrict, user.editEmail);
    app.post('/enable-2fa', restrict, user.enableMfa);
    app.post('/disable-2fa', restrict, user.disableMfa);
    app.post('/withdraw-request', restrict, user.handleWithdrawRequest);
    app.post('/support', restrict, contact('support'));
    app.post('/contact', contact('contact'));
    app.post('/logout', restrictRedirectToHome, user.logout);
    app.post('/login', recaptchaRestrict, user.login);
    app.post('/register', recaptchaRestrict, user.register);

    app.post('/ott', restrict, function(req, res, next) {
        var user = req.user;
        var ipAddress = req.ip;
        var userAgent = req.get('user-agent');
        assert(user);
        database.createOneTimeToken(user.id, ipAddress, userAgent, function(err, token) {
            if (err) {
                console.error('[INTERNAL_ERROR] unable to get OTT got ' + err);
                res.status(500);
                return res.send('Server internal error');
            }
            res.send(token);
        });
    });
    app.get('/stats', stats.index);


    // Admin stuff
    app.get('/admin-giveaway', restrict, admin.giveAway);
    app.post('/admin-giveaway', restrict, admin.giveAwayHandle);

    app.get('*', function(req, res) {
        res.status(404);
        res.render('404');
    });
};
```

**INDEX.JS**

```
var fs = require('fs');

var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var assert = require('assert');
var compression = require('compression');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var socketIO = require('socket.io');
var ioCookieParser = require('socket.io-cookie');
var _ = require('lodash');
var debug = require('debug')('app:index');
var app = express();

var config = require('../config/config');
var routes = require('./routes');
var database = require('./database');
var Chat = require('./chat');
var lib = require('./lib');

debug('booting bustabit webserver');

/** TimeAgo Settings:
 * Simplify and de-verbosify timeago output.
 **/
var timeago = require('timeago');
var timeago_strings = _.extend(timeago.settings.strings, {
  seconds: '< 1 min',
  minute: '1 min',
  minutes: '%d mins',
  hour: '1 hour',
  hours: '%d hours',
  day: '1 day',
  days: '%d days',
  month: '1 month',
  months: '%d months',
  year: '1 year',
  years: '%d years'
});
timeago.settings.strings = timeago_strings;


/** Render Engine
 *
 * Put here render engine global variable trough app.locals
 * **/
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, '../views'));

app.locals.recaptchaKey = config.RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY;
app.locals.buildConfig = config.BUILD;
app.locals.miningFeeBits = config.MINING_FEE/100;

var dotCaching = true;
if (!config.PRODUCTION) {
    app.locals.pretty = true;
    dotCaching = false;
}

app.engine("html", require("dot-emc").init(
    {
        app: app,
        fileExtension:"html",
        options: {
            templateSettings: {
                cache: dotCaching
            }
        }
    }
).__express);


/** Middleware **/
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(compression());


/** App settings **/
app.set("view engine", "html");
app.disable('x-powered-by');
app.enable('trust proxy');


/** Serve Static content **/
var twoWeeksInSeconds = 1209600;
if(config.PRODUCTION) {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../build'), { maxAge: twoWeeksInSeconds * 1000 }));
} else {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client_new'), { maxAge: twoWeeksInSeconds * 1000 }));
    app.use('/client_old', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client_old'), { maxAge: twoWeeksInSeconds * 1000 }));
    app.use('/node_modules', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')), { maxAge: twoWeeksInSeconds * 1000 });
}


/** Login middleware
 *
 * If the user is logged append the user object to the request
 */
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    debug('incoming http request');

    var sessionId = req.cookies.id;

    if (!sessionId) {
        res.header('Vary', 'Accept, Accept-Encoding, Cookie');
        res.header('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=60'); // Cache the logged-out version
        return next();
    }

    res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    res.header("Content-Security-Policy", "frame-ancestors 'none'");


    if (!lib.isUUIDv4(sessionId)) {
        res.clearCookie('id');
        return next();
    }

    database.getUserBySessionId(sessionId, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            res.clearCookie('id');
            if (err === 'NOT_VALID_SESSION') {
                return res.redirect('/');
            } else {
                console.error('[INTERNAL_ERROR] Unable to get user by session id ' + sessionId + ':', err);
                return res.redirect('/error');
            }
        }
        user.advice = req.query.m;
        user.error = req.query.err;
        user.eligible = lib.isEligibleForGiveAway(user.last_giveaway);
        user.admin = user.userclass === 'admin';
        user.moderator = user.userclass === 'admin' ||
                         user.userclass === 'moderator';
        req.user = user;
        next();
    });

});

/** Error Middleware
 *
 * How to handle the errors:
 * If the error is a string: Send it to the client.
 * If the error is an actual: error print it to the server log.
 *
 * We do not use next() to avoid sending error logs to the client
 * so this should be the last middleware in express .
 */
function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {

    if (err) {
        if(typeof err === 'string') {
            return res.render('error', { error: err });
        } else {
            if (err.stack) {
                console.error('[INTERNAL_ERROR] ', err.stack);
            } else console.error('[INTERNAL_ERROR', err);

            res.render('error');
        }

    } else {
        console.warning("A 'next()' call was made without arguments, if this an error or a msg to the client?");
    }

}

routes(app);
app.use(errorHandler);

/**  Server **/
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = socketIO(server); //Socket io must be after the lat app.use
io.use(ioCookieParser);

/** Socket io login middleware **/
io.use(function(socket, next) {
    debug('incoming socket connection');

    var sessionId = (socket.request.headers.cookie)? socket.request.headers.cookie.id : null;

    //If no session id or wrong the user is a guest
    if(!sessionId || !lib.isUUIDv4(sessionId)) {
        socket.user = false;
        return next();
    }

    database.getUserBySessionId(sessionId, function(err, user) {

        //The error is handled manually to avoid sending it into routes
        if (err) {
            if (err === 'NOT_VALID_SESSION') {
                //socket.emit('err', 'NOT_VALID_SESSION');
                next(new Error('NOT_VALID_SESSION'));
            } else {
                console.error('[INTERNAL_ERROR] Unable to get user in socket by session ' + sessionId + ':', err);
                next(new Error('Unable to get the session on the server, logged as a guest.'));
                //return socket.emit('err', 'INTERNAL_ERROR');
            }
            socket.user = false;
            return next();
        }

        //Save the user info in the socket connection object
        socket.user = user;
        socket.user.admin = user.userclass === 'admin';
        socket.user.moderator = user.userclass === 'admin' || user.userclass === 'moderator';
        next();
    });
});


var chatServer = new Chat(io);

server.listen(config.PORT, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port ', config.PORT);
});

/** Log uncaught exceptions and kill the application **/
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.error((new Date).toUTCString() + ' uncaughtException:', err.message);
    console.error(err.stack);
    process.exit(1);
});
```

Comment: Please comment all your code in the router file and just do this first `var router = require('express').Router(); router.get('/',  (req, res) => res.send('hello world!')); module.exports = router` if this works the error will be emanating from one of your routes declaration

Comment: hello working now?

Comment: I will try that, In the meantime sir are you on slack? or any instant messenger? it would be easier then this and at this point I'd offer a reward for it.

Comment: Yes slack, Facebook, whatsapp

Comment: Can I find you on slack by searching your name on here?

Comment: I justed accepted your invite are your Mason H?

Comment: yes I am. I will be back at my PC in just a moment I apologize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the cause of the error please remove this line of code

```
   app.use('/node_modules', 
     express.static(path.join(__dirname, 
       '../node_modules')), { maxAge: twoWeeksInSeconds * 
       1000 });
    }
```

Comment: This worked!! Thank you so much sir for all your help.